# Php: Error when use stream() to open file pdf on browser

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use package laravel-dompdf of by barryvdh to create pdf file.

```
$view = view('pdf.shipper_trip', compact('shipper', 'orders'));
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($view);
return $pdf->stream();
```

But I get exception

> unlink('...'):Permission denied.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This look likes that you don't have enough file system privileges for a folder where the stream stores data.

May this will help you: http://laravel.io/forum/05-08-2014-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied

Comment: I use wamp server local on win. How can i set permission?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396